# Missing New Entry button/dropdown when overriding the Entries Control Panel page

Tags: control-panel

I have developed a module which overrides the entries page in the admin control panel as we need some custom fuctionality on that page. It's mostly working, however when I set the element type in the modules index.twig to the modules element type, the 'New entry' button and the dropdown of entry types disappears in the admin panel. If I change the element type in the custom modules index.twig to craft\elements\Entry, the New entry button and dropdown shows. My custom modules element type entry class extends the craft\elements\Entry, so I'm not sure why the button disappears.

What am I missing?